# Is there a name for the derivative of current with respect to time, or the second derivative of charge with respect to time?

Tags: electromagnetism, terminology

This measurement comes up a lot in my E&M class, in regards to inductance and inductors.

Is there really no conventional term for this?

If not, is there some historical reason for this omission?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nope, not as far as I know. It's just "rate of change of current" or something like that.

I suppose it's possible someone has given it a name in some paper or textbook, but if so, it's not widely used.

Comment: And once you're on friendly terms, "I dot".

Answer (score 0):

It is change of current in unit time. If there is a current, there will be a magnetic field. If there is a change in current, the possibility is an acceleration of charge which leads to the production of electromagnetic waves. So it could be an electric field and/or magnetic field.